# Xaml parsing failed. Visual Studio 2013 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in Sicuro.exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing windows phone 8.1 application. I have map screen. this screen was working perfect but now I'm getting this exception on this screen just.

this.InitializeComponent();

on this I'm getting exception 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'.

I could not get any solution about this. please help me to resolve this. for further information see attachment. [image]

here is my Xaml code.

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneBorderThickness">2.5</Thickness>
    <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
    <FontWeight x:Key="PhoneButtonFontWeight">Semibold</FontWeight>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextStyleLargeFontSize">18.14</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneButtonContentPadding">9.5,0,9.5,3.5</Thickness>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinHeight">57.5</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinWidth">109</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneTouchTargetOverhang">0,9.5</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonFontWeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonContentPadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="PointerOver" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-resource:/Files/Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/check-in@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:/Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/check-in@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/check-in@2x.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Foreground>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/check-in@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Foreground>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>



<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Home_Button" Label="HOME" Icon="Home" Click="Home_button_click">
            <!--<AppBarButton.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/details.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Background>-->

        </AppBarButton>

        <AppBarButton x:Name="Message_Button" Label="MESSAGE" Icon="Message" Click="Message_button_Click"/>

        <AppBarButton x:Name="Map_Button" Label="MAP" Icon="Map" Click="Map_button_Click"/>

        <AppBarButton x:Name="Settings_Button" Label="SETTING" Icon="Setting" Click="Setting_button_Click"/>

    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Main_bg_grid" Background="#FF204371">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sicuro"
                FontSize="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <!--<Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/blur_bg.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>-->


            <Maps:MapControl x:Name="Mymap" MapServiceToken="wu0BD4oAAvgN_rRNqXG7xg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="520" Width="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" ZoomLevel="24" />


        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Width="240" Height="80" Background="Transparent"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,40">

            <Button x:Name="Check_in_button" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Click="Check_In_Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/check-in@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="92"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="92"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/mylocation_btn.png" Tapped="My_Location_Button_Tapped"></Image>
            <!--<Image Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/direction_btn.png"></Image>-->


        </Grid>

        <!--<Image x:Name="location_mark" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Source="Assets/App_images/drawable_xhdpi/location_marker_ic.png" Width="136" Height="102"/>-->
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.Row="1"  
             IsIndeterminate="True"  
             Maximum="100" Value="30"  
             Height="10"  
             Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Here is Call Stack..

> Sicuro.exe!Sicuro.Map.InitializeComponent() Line 44 C#
>       Sicuro.exe!Sicuro.Map.Map() Line 70 C#
>       Sicuro.exe!Sicuro.Sicuro_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_7_Map() Line 200    C#
>       Sicuro.exe!Sicuro.Sicuro_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() Line 502  C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       Sicuro.exe!Sicuro.Dashboard_Screen.Map_button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 259  C#

Comment: please post xaml code to find the problem

Comment: yes sure.. I just post xaml code

Comment: Also post the stack trace. Get it by clicking on ViewDetail,  in the exception Dialog.

Comment: Check if the namespace of the class in the xaml and in the xaml.cs match.

Comment: I just update my xaml code..please check

Comment: By mistake first I upload old xaml code.. I just edit the question. please have a look at this

Comment: @diiN_ yes I have checked this. Namespace is Same.

Comment: Error is in mapscontrol. Please post that code

Comment: <Maps:MapControl x:Name="Mymap" MapServiceToken="wu0BD4oAAvgN_rRNqXG7xg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="520" Width="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" ZoomLevel="24" />    here is map control

Comment: Add ZoomLevel=20. Value should be between 1 to 20

Comment: Got It yar.. Thanks. Yes This was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoomlevel  value of mapscontrol should be between 1 to 20

Comment: Thanks bro.. Got it.